# Send mail through html button

Tags: html, email

I need to send a mail through an HTML button without human intervention, but I am not getting how to add the port and server details into the tag.

I tried this code:

```html
<button onclick="location.href='mailto:xyz@outlook.com?subject=Email Subject&body=Email Body'">Send Email</button>
```

how to add a server & port to the existing code?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with no human intervention and plain HTML and JS. The `mailto` protocol simply opens the user's default desktop application for handling email and prefills some of the information. Unless the user's email client can handle custom headers that trigger an automatic send, some human intervention will likely be required.

Comment: you're using a domain that will be read by a DNS (Domain Name Server) that knows every domain and the server and port that domain is registered to. If you need to use a different port you have to add it right behind the domain such as `xyz@outlook.com:port`. However, HTML is a read-only document that cannot send emails. The `mailto` is just a code piece that will open the user's email client and insert the email address automatically. It still has to be sent manually. You need a backend that has access to the mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to add server and port information to an HTML button tag as the mailto: protocol used in the href attribute does not support specifying a server and port. The mailto: protocol is a simple way to open the default email client installed on the user's device and pre-populate some fields like the recipient email address, subject, and body. If you need to send an email programmatically from a website or application, you can use server-side scripting languages like PHP or Python to send the email using an SMTP server. This approach requires some additional setup, including configuring an SMTP server and providing authentication credentials. Alternatively, you can use a third-party email service provider like SendGrid or Mailgun, which provides APIs that allow you to send emails programmatically without worrying about the underlying infrastructure. These services usually offer free tiers with limited usage, making them a cost-effective option for small-scale applications.

Comment: it is semi-correct. With an URL you already selecting a server. And you can add a port to any URL manually independent of the DNS. See the comment above.